# EFCore IQueryable has count > 0 but ToList( returns 0 records

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

This is my first foray into EF Core after using Telerik Data Access for a couple of years then EF6 when Telerik discontinued their product. This was a pretty basic technique I'd used before but am getting some unexpected results this time.

I have first created a function which I can call that will return an IQueryable of some domain models filled by the corresponding datastore entities ...

```
public static IQueryable<Models.Product> GetProductQuery(DBCtx ctx)
{
    IQueryable<Models.Product> ret = from product in ctx.PRODUCT
                                     select new Models.Product
                                     {
                                         ID          = product.product_id,
                                         Description = product.product_desc,
                                         Name        = product.product_name,
                                         Extract     = product.product_extract,
                                         IsEnabled   = product.is_enabled,
                                         IsFeatured  = product.is_featured,
                                         SKU         = product.product_sku,
                                         Price       = product.product_price,
                                         FamilyID    = product.product_family_id,
                                         Family      = product.product_family_.product_family_name,
                                         LineID      = product.product_line_id,
                                         Line        = product.product_line_.product_line_name,
                                         TypeID      = product.product_type_id,
                                         Type        = product.product_type_.product_type_name
                                     };
    return ret;
}
```

When I run the following in my test method ...

```
using (UNQ.DAL.Models.DBCtx ctx = new DAL.Models.DBCtx ())
{
    var stage = ProductService.GetProductQuery(ctx);

    var products    = stage.ToList();
    var count       = stage.Count();
}
```

the variable, **products**, which should contain 2 product records, returns an empty list ... however ... the variable **count** correctly reflects that there are (should be) 2 records present. How can the count be different from the actual records from the same IQueryable?

I'm 100% stumped ... This pattern is something I have done hundreds of times before in EF6 without issue but now ... Is this an EF Core thing or am I missing something else?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** -- Here's a screen shot of the unit test. You can see in the WATCH window that the products collection has a count of 0 yet ... the value returned by the Count() method is 2 ???

[image]

Comment: How are you checking the variable states. According to your code, the query will be executed only on the line where you have `stage.ToList();`. Apart from that I don't see any reasons for the list to return empty and count as 2.

Comment: Me either! I would expect the **products** variable to be assigned a list containing 2 records. And that's what the **Count()**  method indicates.

Comment: Can you profile the queries that get executed for both `ToList` and `Count`? You can either use the tooling from your database provider. Alternately you can leverage some of the [logging built into EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3).

Comment: The only reason I can think of is, the ToList() call is failing (May be some of the fields in your entity model `product` is not compatible with the `Models.Product` entity. Can you change the query to return just the original entity and check the results..

Comment: What happens if you remove the `count` variable and call in the test, and do instead `var productsFirstTime = stage.ToList(); var productsSecondTime = stage.ToList();`?

Comment: @Thangadurai You appear to have won this one! When I broke down the population of the Product instance the LineID and TypeID were not defined in the database which I am guessing broke some relationship rules between the Product and associated Lines/Types. It is frustrating that when I run the tests no exceptions are thrown, it simply appears that the number of records returned did not match the Assert statement. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Make sure to run context.SaveChanges() from in-memory data context.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#in-memory-provider